# Anonymous Role in springboot project after autenticated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot project

When authenticating in project, after authenticating with the admin account, I encountered an anonymous role.

Can you please advise what is the reason and how to solve it?

Meanwhile, I use Angular as the front end of the project

**This is my webSecurityConfig**

```
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api2/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**Auth Controller:**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api2/auth")
public class AuthController {
        @Autowired
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
        @Autowired
        UserRepository userRepository;
        @Autowired
        RoleRepository roleRepository;
        @Autowired
        PasswordEncoder encoder;
        @Autowired
        JwtUtils jwtUtils;

        @PostMapping("/signin")
        public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                    .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
            ResponseCookie jwtCookie = jwtUtils.generateJwtCookie(userDetails);
            List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                    .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString())
                    .body(new UserInfoResponse(userDetails.getId(),
                            userDetails.getUsername(),
                            userDetails.getPassword(),
                            roles));
        }

        @PostMapping("/signup")
        public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
            if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
            }

            // Create new user's account
            User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(),
                    encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));
            Set<String> strRoles =  signUpRequest.getRole();
            Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
            if (strRoles == null) {
                Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                roles.add(userRole);
            } else {
                strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                    if ("admin".equals(role)) {
                        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(adminRole);

                    } else if ("user".equals(role)) {
                        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(userRole);
                    }
                });
            }
            user.setRoles(roles);
            userRepository.save(user);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
        }

        @PostMapping("/signout")
        public ResponseEntity<?> logoutUser() {
            ResponseCookie cookie = jwtUtils.getCleanJwtCookie();
            return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookie.toString())
                    .body(new MessageResponse("You've been signed out!"));
        }
    }
```

**result of trace:**

> ERROR 2540 ---  c.s.e.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt     : Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource
>
> TRACE 2540 ---  o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
>
> DEBUG 2540 ---  s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
>
> TRACE 2540 --- o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter...]
>
> TRACE 2540 ---  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/13)
>
> TRACE 2540 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/13)
>
> DEBUG 2540 --- s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
>
> TRACE 2540 --- o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/13)
>
> TRACE 2540 --- o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (5/13)
>
> TRACE 2540 ---  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/13)
>
> TRACE 2540 ---  o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
>
> TRACE 2540 ---  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthTokenFilter (7/13)
>
> TRACE 2540 ---  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/13)
>
> TRACE 2540 ---  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/13)
>
> TRACE 2540 ---  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/13)
>
> TRACE 2540 ---[ o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
>
> TRACE 2540 ---  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (11/13)
>
> TRACE 2540 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (12/13)
>
> TRACE 2540 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (13/13)
>
> TRACE 2540 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/api2/auth/**'] - [permitAll] (1/2)
>
> TRACE 2540 ---o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not re-authenticate AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] before authorizing
>
> TRACE 2540 ---  o.s.s.w.a.expression.WebExpressionVoter  : Voted to deny authorization
>
> TRACE 2540 ---  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /product/slider] with attributes [authenticated] using AffirmativeBased [DecisionVoters=[org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1dcad16f], AllowIfAllAbstainDecisions=false]
>
> TRACE 2540 ---  o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

> **Added**

> ERROR 8184 ---  c.s.e.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt     : Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource >

> TRACE 8184 --- o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure] >

> DEBUG 8184 --- s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request

Project classes:

[image]

**Thank you for your time**

I tried many ways from stackoverflow and other places to solve this problem, but I didn't get any results.

Comment: Why did you exclude the `SecurityAutoConfiguration` class?

Comment: @fatih I do not have such a class in the project.
I am attaching the available classes in a photo

Comment: Can you try to remove the exclude part for `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in `WebSecurityConfig` class?

Comment: @fatih i deleted .A few lines were added to the trace results which I added